# Faster way to write these multiple elseif?

Tags: php

is there a way for simpler and faster way to write this?

```
$currTime = date('H:i');
if ($currTime >= "12:09" && $currTime <= "16:08") {
    echo rand(260, 272);
} elseif ($currTime >= "16:09" && $currTime <= "18:08") {
    echo rand(278, 286);
} elseif ($currTime >= "18:09" && $currTime <= "20:08") {
    echo rand(293, 303);
} elseif ($currTime >= "20:09" && $currTime <= "23:38") {
    echo rand(338, 359);
} elseif ($currTime >= "23:39" && $currTime <= "23:59") {
    echo rand(293, 302);
} elseif ($currTime >= "01:06" && $currTime <= "02:08") {
    echo rand(195, 210);
} elseif ($currTime >= "02:09" && $currTime <= "02:23") {
    echo rand(168, 179);
} elseif ($currTime >= "02:24" && $currTime <= "07:08") {
    echo rand(121, 128);
} elseif ($currTime >= "07:09" && $currTime <= "09:08") {
    echo rand(143, 160);
} elseif ($currTime >= "09:09" && $currTime <= "12:08") {
    echo rand(187, 207);
} else {
    echo rand(233, 241);
}
```

Comment: `switch()` maybe, but with this few conditions, performance gain would be negligible.

Comment: @Revent switch doesn't have ranges. One thing I'd say is there really is no need to have the first condition in each check; just add a new condition at the top for less than `12:09`. No more elegant way springs to mind. It would be faster to pre convert to ints, but php is slow anyway so I wouldn't care about that too much.

Comment: Can you even do a switch statement with conditions ($a < $b && $b < c)? I don't think you can, in which case what you have above is probably the best and cleanest option.

Comment: @jraede yes you can do switch that way

Comment: Ok, then how do you do it?

Comment: Probably a more maintainable way is making an array with `array(mintime, maxtime, minrand,maxrand)` entries, looping through it, `if(mintime <= time && maxtime >= time){ echo rand(minrand,maxrand);break}`. So you only need to fiddle with the array later instead of altering the logic. BTW: you can of course `switch(true){ case $currTime >= "12:09" && $currTime <= "16:08":...etc.`, but that isn't any cleaner.

Comment: @jraede I think Baba's referring to `switch(true)` and putting the conditions in the case statements. It's the worst abuse of switch statements I've ever known, and sadly seems to be popular in php. The baffling part is that it gives absolutely no benefits over if/else chaining.

Answer (score 3):

```
$currTime = date('H:i');

$timevals=Array(
"23:39" => Array(293,302),
"20:09" => Array(338,359),
"18:09" => Array(293,303),
//... (etc, descending order)
);

foreach($timevals AS $time => $vals) {
  if($curtime >=$time) {
    echo rand($vals[0],$vals[1]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to make it obvious to the OP - so long as your times are in order, you only have to test that the time is greater than one time before moving onto the next (until you get to midnight).

Answer (score 3):

Don't look at faster way ... Look at proper ways ....

- Never compare `date` or `time` like `strings`
- use `mt_rand` instead of `rand`
- Use `functions` or `object` rather than long switch or if else

Example :

```
$currTime = new DateTime();

$range = [
        new TimeRange("12:09-16:08", "260-272"),
        new TimeRange("16:09-18:08", "278-286"),
        new TimeRange("18:09-20:08", "293-303"),
        new TimeRange("20:09-23:38", "338-359"),
        new TimeRange("23:39-23:59", "195-210"),
        new TimeRange("01:06-02:23", "168-179"),
        new TimeRange("02:24-07:08", "121-128"),
        new TimeRange("07:09-09:08", "143-160"),
        new TimeRange("09:09-12:08", "187-241")
];

foreach($range as $timeRange) {
    if ($timeRange->inRange($currTime)) {
        printf("Current Time\t: %s\n", $currTime->format("H:i"));
        printf("Range Time\t: %s\n", $timeRange->getRange());
        printf("Random Value\t: %s\n", $timeRange->getRandom());
        break;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Current Time    : 01:53
Range Time      : 01:06 - 02:23
Random Value    : 168
```

Used Class

```
class TimeRange {
    private $timeFrom, $timeTo;
    private $numFrom, $numTo;
    private $format;

    function __construct($time, $number, $format = "H:i") {
        list($timeFrom, $timeTo) = explode("-", $time);
        list($this->numFrom, $this->numTo) = explode("-", $number);
        $this->timeFrom = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $timeFrom);
        $this->timeTo = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $timeTo);
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    function inRange(DateTime $currTime) {
        return $currTime >= $this->timeFrom && $currTime <= $this->timeTo;
    }

    function getRandom() {
        return mt_rand($this->numFrom, $this->numTo);
    }

    function getRange() {
        return sprintf("%s - %s", $this->timeFrom->format($this->format), $this->timeTo->format($this->format));
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't creating an entire class for this a bit overkill? You can just get the integer equivalent of a time by using `strtotime()`

Comment: [To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) .. and its not as expensive as you think

Comment: Not worried about processing time - just the fact that writing an entire class for this simple comparator seems like a waste of time when the problem you're trying to address can be solved with `strtotime()`. There won't be any ambiguity as he is using just times.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cleaner way to do this, a *switch* statement will not work in this case. All you can do is make your if's a little shorter, but that's about it. I think your approach in this situation is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Take my solution) This shortens and simplifies the code..

```
<?
function plan($a, $b, $c, $d)
{
    $t = date('H:i');
    if ($a <= $t && $t <= $b) { echo rand($c, $d); }
}
plan("12:09", "16:08", 260, 272);
plan("16:09", "18:08", 278, 286);
plan("18:09", "20:08", 293, 303);
plan("20:09", "23:38", 338, 359);
plan("23:39", "23:59", 293, 302);
plan("00:00", "01:05", 233, 241);
plan("01:06", "02:08", 195, 210);
plan("02:09", "02:23", 168, 179);
plan("02:24", "07:08", 121, 128);
plan("07:09", "09:08", 143, 160);
plan("09:09", "12:08", 187, 207);
?>
```

Comment: Ou... How we can compare two string values? :p

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.phpbench.com/

### Control Structures

`switch/case/default` VS. `if/elseif/else`

```
Control Structures               | Total time
---------------------------------|-----------
if and elseif (using ==)         | 190 µs
if, elseif and else (using ==)   | 189 µs
if and elseif (using ===)        | 158 µs
if, elseif and else (using ===)  | 170 µs
switch / case                    | 200 µs
switch / case / default`         | 228 µs
```

**Conclusion:**

Using a `switch/case` or `if/elseif` is *almost the same*. **Note** that the test is unsing `===` (is exactly equal to) and is slightly faster then using `==` (is equal to).

Answer (score 0):

```
$currTime = date('H:i');


$arr=array

(
"12:09,16:08"=>'260,272',
"16:09,18:08"=>'278, 286',
"18:09,20:08"=>'293, 303',
"20:09,23:38"=>'338, 359',
"23:39,23:59"=>'293, 302',
"01:06,02:08"=>'195, 210',
"00:00,00:30" =>'1,10'
//etc,etc...

);

foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {



$key=explode(',',$key);
$value=explode(',',$value);

if( $currTime>= $key[0] && $currTime<=$key[1]) {
echo  rand($value[0],$value[1]);    

}




}


...however, i would keep OP's code as it is... :)
```